# NSTableCellView Image View action

Tags: cocoa, xamarin, action, nstableview, xamarin.mac

I need to call catch action of ImageView inside NSTableCellView.

I add some action for it, but when I click the row action is not called...
[image]

I have set accept touch event property true, but no result

```
PatientTableView.AcceptsTouchEvents = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

image view does not support click action (use NSButton for that).

It does support an action when a user drags an image on to it (if the imageview is set to editable). Never used this thought. I never use actions in xcode. But always subscribe to an event on the control in c#. For the default action this is the Activated event.